# How to sign out from instagram api in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

The instagram integration and login has been done.  How to sign out from instagram api in iOS? How to remove the access token?

Comment: Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [M.C.V E](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Answer (score 0):

You can logout the user by deleting the cookies.

```
   let cookieJar : NSHTTPCookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
    for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! as [NSHTTPCookie]{
        NSLog("cookie.domain = %@", cookie.domain)

        if cookie.domain == "www.instagram.com" ||
            cookie.domain == "api.instagram.com"{

            cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is what we use. Note that the domain has to be ".instagram.com" not "www.instagram.com" since some cookies do not have the "www". Also the main cookie is "sessionid".

```
 override func signOut() {
    if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
        for cookie in cookies {
            if cookie.domain.contains(".instagram.com") {
                HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

InstagramEngine.shared().logout()